# How can i move items programmatically on the screen?

Tags: android, image, position, screen

I have an image with an item in the lower left. I would like at the bottom center, and not attached at the lower end but slightly raised. How can I do? Working with some of the calculations on the size of the screen? Obviously I mean in code, not xml. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

for exmaple

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Button button1;
button1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

you can do all differnt alignments, params, margins and padding as in xml

Comment: i try with layout params but nothing work like i want.